# How to store data for use in all tabs in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've got an application that downloads data from a remote database and display that data in 3 different tabs. Right now I download the same data 3 times for each tab but I want to download and update it just once. My goal is to store the data and access it globally or pass it as props from the main App to the tabs. At the same time, I want that data updated every few seconds. I've tried using mobx and react hooks but I don't know how to apply it to my app.

This is the code that I have in App.js:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import Motor1Screen from './screens/Motor1Screen';
import Motor2Screen from './screens/Motor2Screen';
import Motor3Screen from './screens/Motor3Screen';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

export const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    "G1": Motor1Screen,
    "G2": Motor2Screen,
    "G3": Motor3Screen,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: "rgba(16,110,242,1)",
      shifting: true,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
        height: 70,
      },
    },
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
        focused
          ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', marginBottom: 5, marginTop: -5 }}> {navigation.state.routeName} </Text>
          : <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'center', color: 'rgba(16,110,242,1)', marginBottom: 5, marginTop: -5 }}> {navigation.state.routeName} </Text>
      ),
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        focused
          ? <Icon name="engine" size={35} color="white" />
          : <Icon name="engine-outline" size={30} color="rgba(16,110,242,1)" />
      ),
    }),
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code that I use in one of the screens:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import GMarcha from '../components/GMarcha';
import CompNum from '../components/CompNum';
import CompOnOff from '../components/CompOnOff';

export default class Motor3Screen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datos: []
    }
  }

  getDatos = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:44325/api/Variables`);
      const json = response.ok ? await response.json() : console.log("Error");
      this.setState({ datos: json });
      console.log(this.state.datos);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getDatos()
    }, 10000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GMarcha GMarcha={this.state.datos.G3Marcha} />
        <View style={{ margin: 7 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
              <CompNum value={this.state.datos.G3Gripper} nom="Gripper" />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
              <CompOnOff value={this.state.datos.G1Tritur} nom="Celda del robot" text1="Abierta" text0="Cerrada" icon1="lock-open" icon0="lock" />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 10,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
  },
});
```

Comment: Use AsyncStorage you can store data locally in your device and use it anywhere in your all Application

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to store the data and access it globally or pass it as props from the main App to the tabs

You need to use a global store like MobX State Tree, Overmind or Redux.